# The Delete operation In Red Black Tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, red-black-tree

Recently , I'm learning the Left Lean Red Black Tree. And I red [this](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/LLRB/LLRB.pdf) to help me learn . However , I can not get the meaning of the codes in the **delete** operation, they are :

```
if (isRed(h.left))h = rotateRight(h);
```

I just can't find a good example to help me to get the usage of this code.

Can anybody helps to give me the reason why the code should be there (with a tiny example is much better) ?

Comment: If `h.left` is red, then rotate `h` right and assign to `h`?

Answer (score 0):

Page 7 of the PDF contains the full function.  Basically what it is doing, if the line is "red" (meaning it was added to force the tree to be a LLRBT), then rotate the left child node in it's place.

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
```

If I'm deleting A, I'd rotate B to it's place:

```
    B
     \
      C
```